# CORS Issue with Vue.js and Flask: XMLHttpRequest Blocked

Tags: python, vue.js, flask, cors

Description:

I'm building a web application using Vue.js for the frontend and Flask for the backend. I'm starting with a simple login page. However, I'm encountering a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issue when making requests from my Vue.js application to my Flask backend.

Problem:

When I try to make a POST request from my Vue.js application at http://localhost:8081 to my Flask server at http://localhost:5000, I receive the following error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/login' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Code:

LoginForm.vue

```
  <div>
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form @submit.prevent="login">
      <div>
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" v-model="username" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" v-model="password" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
    <div>{{ message }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      username: '',
      password: '',
      message: '',
    };
  },
  
  methods: {
    async login() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/login', {
          username: this.username,
          password: this.password,
        });

        if (response.status === 200) {
          this.message = 'Login successful!';
        } else {
          this.message = 'Invalid credentials';
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('An error occurred:', error);
      }
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from itsdangerous import TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer as Serializer
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "http://localhost:8081"}})

# Sample user data (for demo purposes)
users = [
    {"username": "user1", "password": "password1"},
    {"username": "user2", "password": "password2"},
]

SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(24)

def generate_user_token():
    serializer = Serializer(SECRET_KEY, expires_in=3600)

    token_data = {'is_admin': True}

    token = serializer.dumps(token_data).decode('utf-8')

    return token

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin(origin="http://localhost:8081", supports_credentials=True)
def login():
    data = request.get_json()
    username = data.get('username')
    password = data.get('password')

    for user in users:
        if user['username'] == username and user['password'] == password:
            if username == 'user1':
                token = generate_user_token()  
                return make_response(jsonify({'token': token}), 201)
            return jsonify({"message": "Login successful!"}), 200

    # Returns 403 if the password is wrong
    return make_response(
        'Could not verify',
        403,
        {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Wrong Password !!"'}
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Request:

I would appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this CORS issue and enable communication between my Vue.js and Flask applications. Are there any additional steps I should take to ensure proper CORS configuration?

What I've Tried:

-I have installed Flask-CORS and configured it in my Flask app.
-I added the necessary CORS headers in my Flask routes, including the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.
-I have ensured that my Vue.js application and Flask server are running on the specified ports.

Despite these efforts, the CORS issue persists, and I'm unable to make requests from my Vue.js application to the Flask backend.

[Request Headers from Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQEt1.png)

[Response Header from Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2Ioj.png)

Answer (score 0):

It works fine when I correct code like below

[image]

Here is my request

[image]

Here is my result
[image]

[image]

Below is complete code

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
# This line will lead to below error so I correct TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer to URLSafeTimedSerializer
# "ImportError: cannot import name 'TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer' from 'itsdangerous'
from itsdangerous import URLSafeTimedSerializer as Serializer 
import os
import time

app = Flask(__name__)
# This line is no need so I commented
# CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "http://localhost:8081"}})

# Sample user data (for demo purposes)
users = [
    {"username": "user1", "password": "password1"},
    {"username": "user2", "password": "password2"},
]

SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(24)

def generate_user_token():
    serializer = Serializer(SECRET_KEY)

    token_data = {'is_admin': True,'expire_time': time.time() + 3600}
    # Move expires_in to here
    token = serializer.dumps(token_data)

    return token

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin(origin="*", supports_credentials=True)
def login():
    data = request.get_json()
    username = data.get('username')
    password = data.get('password')

    for user in users:
        if user['username'] == username and user['password'] == password:
            if username == 'user1':
                token = generate_user_token()  
                return make_response(jsonify({'token': token}), 201)
            return jsonify({"message": "Login successful!"}), 200

    # Returns 403 if the password is wrong
    return make_response(
        'Could not verify',
        403,
        {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Wrong Password !!"'}
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: But my vue js is running on http://localhost:8081

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to handle this is to set up a proxy system. Go to the `vue.config.js` file in the root of the vue project, and if it does not exist, create one.
In it, type the following code:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
   proxy: {
    '^/api': {
      target: 'http://localhost:5000/',
      ws: true,
      changeOrigin: true
     },
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i handled CORS in flask app using :

```
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
CORS(app, support_credentials=True)
```

and in the routes :

```
@app.route('/api/admin_login' , methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
def admin_Login():
   # codes!

   # responses
   return make_response(jsonify({'token' : token.decode('UTF-8')}), 201)
    # returns 403 if password is wrong
    return make_response(
        'Could not verify',
        403,
        {'WWW-Authenticate' : 'Basic realm ="Wrong Password !!"'}
    )
```

Comment: The issue still persista

Comment: if you are using postman to check your api, can you add a screenshot from your response header?

Comment: I have added it

Comment: it seems like your request header, i asked for response header

Comment: Sorry about that. Ive added the response header

Comment: did you add @cross_origin(supports_credentials=True) on the route you are using ?

Comment: Yes I did add that

Comment: you are adding access origin and cross origin to your response however their not added to your response header, i added make response to my code, it should work as expected and it's working in my code with flask and react

Comment: I've updated the code. Does it look right? Cause it still doesnt work

Comment: Im using Vue js btw

Comment: you are using jsonify directly, use make response as i used. it doesnt depend on your front-end framework. and i think there is no need to add option and adding header for it. remove it

Comment: Please check. I'm new to Vue js and flask so sorry about this

Comment: I also want to add that even though i installed flask-cors, I get this warning 'Import "flask_cors" could not be resolved from source'

Comment: did you installed flask cor with pip ?

Comment: run " pip install flask_cors" in your terminal

Comment: I've done that and it still persists